# C# Inter Process Communication accross different users

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, ipc

I wanted to send data from one process to another, [Anonymous Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx) and [Memory Mapped Files (Non Persisted)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) were the best solutions, except when the processes are being run by different users they don't work.

Using a TCP connection works but it is exposed to the network and I don't want that (I check and reject address that is not 127.0.0.1).

Named pipes require to be predefined, my program will act pretty much like a webserver, so clients connect, do some stuff, get data then close connection, and multiple clients might be served in parallel, is that possible with named pipes?

Is there a way to make the first two work across different users? or is there another simple solution?

Comment: what about using the Loopback Adapter... that isn't exposed to the network, is it?

Comment: Use 127.0.0.1 as an address.

Comment: XDMessaging is a robust, free alternative for your task: http://thecodeking.github.io/XDMessaging.Net/